# How do you install a package offline within an ISO setup?

Tags: debian, software-installation, pulseaudio, apt-offline

I need to use pulseaudio in Debian environment. I can normally just download it using `sudo apt update; sudo apt install pulseaudio;` But the environment it will be set in will be offline. I'm hoping to package it within an upgrade pkg for an ISO which is what will install the Debian environment. I'm not sure how I'd go about packaging it to allow this feature.

Any hints/docs with info to allow this will be appreciated!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would like to create a tailored debian installation ISO. There is a guide on the [debian homepage](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First on a networked computer use:

```
apt-get install --download-only <package>
```

to get the package. Then copy it from apt-get install --download-only to a USB  thumb drive.

Don't for get to fetch all it's dependencies too. (dpkg -I <package.deb>)

To install:

```
dpkg -i <list of deb packages>
```